# Python: conditional switch statement with addition operation

Tags: python, if-statement, addition

I am trying to define a switch/conditional statement that identifies if an addition operation of two scalar variables fits one of three scenarios namely increase, decrease and change/cross (negative to positive) e.g.

increase:

```
A = 5
B = 5
A + B = 10

A = -5
B = -5
A + B = -10

A = 0
B = 5
A + B = 5

A = 0
B = -5
A + B = 5
```

decrease:

```
A = 5
B = -2
A + B = 3

A = 5
B = -5
A + B = 0

A = -5
B = 5
A + B = 0
```

cross:

```
A = -5
   B = 10
   A + B = 5
```

I have tried implementing the logic in python as follows.

```
C = A + B
if (abs(0-C)<abs(B)):
   print("The addition of A and B is a CROSS type")
elif (abs(0-C)>abs(B)):
   print("The addition of A and B is an INCREASE type")
else:
   print("The addition of A and B is an DECREASE type")
```

Obviously this fails, I was hoping to get some advice on how I could best implement this. Your help here would be great, Thanks.

Comment: What about the case where A and B are both negative?

Comment: It would be an increase, thanks for the response

Comment: Exactly, I know but the math would show that it would be decreasing but I need to categorize it as an increasing example...

Comment: Obviously the Increasing, Decreasing and Cross states are arbitrary names that have no relevance to the problem might as well be situation 1, 2 and 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
if C * A < 0:
    print('cross')
elif abs(A) > abs(C):
    print('decrease')
else 
    print('increase')
```

This also works with the -5 -5 = -10 -> increase case

Answer (score 0):

assuming `c = a + b`
The cross can be made with two checks `if (a > 0 and c < 0) or (a < 0 and c > 0)`

Normally mathematically this is how you would measure the increase, decrease.
for increase and decrease you can just check `if a > c: increase` `if a < C: decrease`

Edit after reading your commments; you actually need to check the cross case first and then if the absolute value is greater or less than to determine the type of "increase/decrease" you want.

`if abs(a) > abs(c): decrease`

`elif abs(a) < abs(c): increase`

`else: no change`

you have to check the cross situation first to ensure that `a` and `c` have the same sign.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
if sign(C) != sign(A): print("cross")
elif abs(C) < abs(A): print("decrease")
else: print("increase")
```

`sign`is taken from `numpy`. I've added the `abs`for the A, B < 0 case. THX @ Marc